# Strange socket.io.js error on client side

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm getting these strange error during my attempts to get socket.io working.

[image: Console]

Also, my socket.io.js file appears like this in chrome:

[image: weird error]

I know my socket.io.js file does not have this within it.

My client code is as follow:

```
// Set up sockets
var socket = io.connect();

socket.on('statusMessage', function(data){
    console.log(data.message);
});
```

My server code is as follows

```
var serv_io = io.listen(server);
serv_io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.emit('statusMessage', {'message': 'Succesfully connected to serve via   sockets'});
});
```

I am also requiring socket.io in a simple way:

```
var io = require('socket.io');
```

I am also deploying on Heroku.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Please show the code where you initialise socket.io in node.js, as well which port your node.js is listening and how you are loading your socket.io in front-end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out my error. And it was a very simple error. I wasn't including `socket.io.js` properly on my HTML file.

When using the socket.io library, the client side JavaScript doesn't need to be manually downloaded and included. You own node.js server actually serves it.

I just had to include:

```
<script src = "/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```